# TFS Reporting pointing to old server

Tags: tfs, reporting

I had a problem with TFS that forced me to restore TFS to a new server. Everything is working fine except for the Warehouse, Analysis Services and the Reports.
Mainly the report keeps pointing to the old server, and when I try to edit it by pointing to new server TFS Administration Console returns the following message:

[image]

I do not wish to restore my old reports; I would like to create all the TFS reporting from scratch. Would someone please point me to the correct place to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Several things I need clarify first in order to better understand your scenario: 1). Does the report server host on the same server as Tfs related databases? 2). Can you find any detailed error message on the Logs page on Administrator Console? 3). Can you connect to that database directly in Sql Server Management Studio? Be sure that you follow the correct steps to configure to target to the new server. (check my replies for the details)

Comment: 1). Yes it does; the server hosts both TFS and Reporting databases. 2). I was not able to find any logs after getting the error - I checked the Configuration Logs in the TFS Administration Console. Is there any other place to check?. 3). I am able to connect normally to the database using SQL management studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was finally solved by clicking the "Specify non-default instance" checkbox, without entering any value in the following combobox. TFS has created the Warehouse and Analysis database by itself.

Answer (score 0):

To target the report to the new server, please follow the steps below:

1). Go the TFS Administration Console, go to **Application Tier** -> **Reporting**, then click the Edit link.

2). On the **Reporting** dialog, check the **Use Reporting** checkbox.

3). On the Warehouse tab, type the new server name on the Server field.

[image]

4). On the Analysis Service tab, specify the new server name in the Server field, Database name, and user account information.

[image]

5). On the Reports tab, type your new server name and click the **Populate URLs** button to have these reporting server URLs populated. Then type the user account information.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did, then I got the error that I mentioned in my question.  These databases were restored from a different server to this new server. The problem is that I need to create a new team project and TFS is not allowing me because the reporting is connecting to the old server: TF218027: The following reporting folder could not be created on the server that is running SQL Server Reporting Services: /TfsReports/Collection. The report server is located at: http://OldServer/Reports. The error is: TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from the server.